# Angular text input filter initializes with no results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic angular app that sorts and filters a list of species from a local json file.  When the app initializes none of the species are returned.  When you begin to type some species are returned, and if you delete your search terms all species are returned.

I would like all species to be returned when the app initializes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0DOwSvtaepSfFWKR8UGS?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's neater to use the inline notation for filter, which avoids this problem:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in species | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp")>
```

**NOTE**: you can then remove the code that sets up the `$watch` on `query`

**EDIT**: as you specifically want it in the controller:

The reason your filter is initialising to blank, is because your $scope.species data is being populated asynchronously. When the first `$watch` is triggered, there is no data to filter. This stays the case until you input a query.

To solve this, set up the `$watch` after the data has arrived, like so:

```
$http.get('species.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.species = data;
    $scope.$watch('query', function (query) {
        $scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.species, query);
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could manually run the filter function once, inside the `success` callback.

Comment: The reason I moved this to the controller is so that it can be reused in different views.  I just have the one view right now, but I'm going to add a "table" view as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting filteredData to the data returned from the get?

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5CSEKzFZbNCr7Q6j15e?p=info)